# View all of an individual's sharepoint permissions in Sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Is there a way to view all of an individual's permissions in an entire Sharepoint 2007 environment ie, all sites, lists, libraries, etc? I know I can do this with Groups by selecting View Group permissions under Advanced Permissions. How do I with Individuals? I don't what and where the previous ITs gave users permissions to and we have thousands of areas and several hundred users. This is too much for a site by site verification. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I use [Access Checker WebPart](http://accesschecker.codeplex.com/) for MOSS 2007.